# Opening a file in a new tab of the web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which shows a list of xml files in a directory. Also i have a button which would display the content of the file name selected in the browser. Currently its showing the content in a the same tab. But i want to display it in a new tab of the browser..
for example if i select two file names from the list, then it should open different tab for both the files..
Please find the code below.

```
public ActionResult ViewFile(string[] Name)
{
byte[] ImageData = null;

for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
{

string filepath = holdpath + @"\" + Name[i];
string result;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
{
result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

}
using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
document.Open();

Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Add(result);
document.Add(paragraph);

document.Close();
ImageData = memoryStream.ToArray();
}


}
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=MyFile.pdf");
return File(ImageData, "application/pdf");
}
```

Please note that i am using itextsharp because the file also needs to be downloaded as pdf if required

**I have added the View here**

```
@model IEnumerable<FileInfo>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "files";
}

<h2>Held files</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div style="border:solid;width:100%;overflow-x:auto;">
<table  align="center" style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>File Name</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (FileInfo file in Model)
{
<tr>

<td>
<input type="checkbox" name="Name" value="@file.Name" />
@file.Name
</td>
<td>
@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewFile", "HoldFiles", new { Name = file.Name }, 
new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm", target = "_blank" })

</td>        
</tr>

}
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Yer not gonna do it from the Controller.  Check out the `target` attribute for the HTML `a`nchor element.

Comment: Can you give me any example or some link :) @SamAxe

Comment: [HTML <a> target Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).

Answer (score 3):

In your view, put `target="_blank"` on your anchor element.

For example:

```
<a href="https://www.url.com" target="_blank">Open in new tab</a>
```

or if using razor:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Text", "ActionMethodName", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm", target = "_blank" })
```

Comment: I know that downvoters thinking that I'm not answering the OP's question completely, specifically this part - _"for example if i select two file names from the list, then it should open different tab for both the files."_, but this answer will give him some minor idea, how should he do that. Well somehow he is selecting that two elements, right? I assume with javascript, so when pressing button, he can get that elements, and for example, click on that links or whatever he prefers.

Comment: i am using razor.but i am a bit confused about the id part.. in my case i have to display a file that has been selected and its present in my local directory..New tab is opening but with error..

Comment: that id part is your `routeValues` that you passing from view to controller, its just an example, you need to write yours.

Comment: i have added the code for View.. Its saying resource cannot be found

Comment: Can you please share your view code? Those links part.

Comment: I have edited the question..you can find the view code there

Comment: @Ksingh `Name` is `string[]`, you passing `string`.

Comment: I changed it to string in my controller.. Still says the same error

Comment: Try to debug, does it hit your action method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157879/discussion-between-sem--and-ksingh).